# My Training job does not seem to complete

Tags: microsoft-translator

Here is the project that I have created in your new Custom Translator platform:
https://portal.customtranslator.azure.ai/Scripts/NgApp/text-translator/projects/7f1b6f9a-d4f4-4ea1-8492-69075339422f

I have tried to run the a training session several time but it does not seem to complete. 
I have made sure to add my subscription, could you please verify where there is something that I am doing wrong? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have three training jobs which have completed, two with success and one has failed. Please check and reach out to Custom Translator support at custommt@microsoft.com for further questions about the Custom Translator.